# RecyclerView: How to clear the recycled views from RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is the situation: RecyclerView item views have a complex layout. 

At some point I modify the layout for RecyclerView items this way:

**Ex. Index of modified View inside itemView = 3;**

```
for (int i=0; i < mRecyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {

    ViewGroup itemView = ((ViewGroup) mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i));

    itemView.getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
    itemView.getChildAt(3).requestLayout();
}
```

It all works as expected but when I scroll  the RecyclerView there are 2-3 recycled item views that will appear with the old width. Now I'm trying to find how to remove these views from RecycledViewPool or even a better solution: to modify their width too but I can't find a way to get those views.

I tried `mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear()` but the old views keeped reappearing.

Comment: you need to notify also after the 
mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 11):

To prevent RecyclerView caching the detached but not recycled views use:

```
mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0)
```

Another slightly more radical way is to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged()` for the items you expect to be cached - this will force them to get recycled and you will be able to update them in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: Great! It works best, if you want to manipulate views inside the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to get the views from RecycledViewPool but I found out that there are also views that are detached from RecyclerView but not recycled yet. So this is the solution that really works if you want to modify the width of views inside all itemViews.

**Ex. Index of modified View inside itemView = 3;**

First modify the width of all visible Views:

```
for (int i=0; i < mRecyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {

    ViewGroup itemView = ((ViewGroup) mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i));

    itemView.getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
    itemView.getChildAt(3).requestLayout();
}
```

Then modify the width of the itemViews that were detached from RecyclerView. This includes recycled itemViews and detached views (but not recycled yet).

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

    ((ViewGroup) holder.itemView).getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1. When init :

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
```

2. When refresh data:

```
recyclerView.removeAllViews();

recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,adapter.getItemCount());
```

Just do this before for loop.

Comment: my app was crashing every time the number of items collided with the item position on the recycler adapter. That single line of code before the 'Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' solved the crash for me on Android SDK 31

Answer (score 0):

Me too have the same problem. I have initially used some set of Items into my RecyclerView. While reaching the last index, I have added some data. Added data is overlapping the view of the previous view. While recycling, the previous view must be deleted. But it will not delete that view. Hence I have used the following code,

```
public override void OnViewRecycled(Java.Lang.Object holder)
    {
        var MyHolder = holder as ViewHolder;
        (MyHolder.ItemView as ImageView).RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
        base.OnViewRecycled(MyHolder);

    }
```

In recyclerview , we have override method like OnViewRecycled. By clearing the view-holder view, we can refresh the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourViewHolder> {

...

private RecyclerView parent;

@NonNull
@Override
public YourAdapter.YourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    this.parent = ((RecyclerView) parent);
...
}

@Override public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull YourViewHolder holder) {
    parent.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
    setLayoutParamsToView(holder.itemView);
}

...

}
```